# Why do I have to call the Cast<> extension method on a DataGridViewRow?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, datagridview

This doesn't work.

```
var result = 
    from row in grid.Rows
    where (string) row.Cells["COLUMN_1"].Value == "Test"
    select row.Cells["COLUMN_2"].Value as int?;
```

But this does.

```
var result = 
    from row in grid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    where (string) row.Cells["COLUMN_1"].Value == "Test"
    select row.Cells["COLUMN_2"].Value as int?;
```

As far as I can tell, the DataGridViewRowCollection is a collection of DataGridViewRows. So why do I have to cast each member to a DataGridViewRow before I can access its properties?

Does it have anything to do with the fact that DataGridViewRowCollection implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` but not the generic version `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`? Or that it apparently uses an `ArrayList` internally? It's not causing me any real problems, but I'd like to understand it better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's exactly because of the interface it advertises. Almost all the extension methods in LINQ work on `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IEnumerable`. `Cast<>` is one way of bridging that gap - `OfType<>` is another.

However, there's a simpler way of calling `Cast<T>` - just explicitly type your range variable:

```
var result = 
    from DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows
    where (string) row.Cells["COLUMN_1"].Value == "Test"
    select row.Cells["COLUMN_2"].Value as int?;
```

The compiler turns this into exactly the same code as your second sample.