# LINQ to DataGridViewRowCollection

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I have a bit of a mystery regarding a LINQ query on a DataGridViewRowCollection.  Here is my query (where "grid" is a DataGridView object):

```
var rows = from DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows
           where row.Selected
           select row;
```

I have a project which contains this query and it executes perfectly.  The problem is that in another project, I get the following error when I try to build the solution:

```
error CS1936: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'.  'Where' not found.
```

At first I thought that it was a reference issue, but I'm using the same references in both projects:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.EntityModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why my LINQ query would work in one project but not the other?

**Edit 1:**

For the record, here is the exact context where the query **is** working:

```
public List<Int64> ComponentIDs
{
    get
    {
        return
            (
                from DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows
                where row.Selected
                select (Int64)row.Cells[0].Value

            ).ToList();

    }

}
```

**Edit 2:**

I just came across the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046916/why-do-i-have-to-call-the-cast-extension-method-on-a-datagridviewrow)...see the accepted answer...this is what I'm trying to do.  For some reason I can't get the IEnumerable.Cast() extension method to work...what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have *exactly* the same LINQ query in both places? (By the way, those are using directives, not references. There's a big difference between namespaces and assemblies.)

Comment: Thanks, Jon for correcting my incorrect use of the word "reference"! =)  Yes, I am using the exact same LINQ query in both places.  I must confess that this is quite baffling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using DataGridViewRowCollection object in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648657/using-datagridviewrowcollection-object-in-linq)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually I don't think your code looks exactly like that. Since `DataGridViewRowCollection` does not implement `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>` your have to use `Cast<DataGridViewRow>()` like this:

```
var rows = from row in grid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
           where row.Selected
           select row;
```

Comment: Hi Magnus...thanks for your reply.  I can assure you that my code looks exactly like the way that I posted it.  I don't seem to have the Cast<>() extension method...how can I get this??

Comment: Hi Magnus...Please see my Edit 2.

Comment: You can find it in `System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast`

Comment: Gee...I feel like an idiot.  The problem is that I had created my own Cast<>() extension method for the Object class and it was being used instead of the IEnumerable.Cast<>() method.  Once I took out that custom extension method, everything worked.  I wish I could split the credit between Pranay and Magnus, however, it was Magnus's post that ultimately led me to the solution...the credit will go to him.  Thanks to everyone who commented!

Comment: @HydroPowerDeveloper so I was right ;) I knew it! That will teach me to delete my answers. +1 for Magnus